# TokenMismatchException in laravel while integration of paytm

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, paytm

I am facing issue with paytm gateway integration in LARAVEL.

My `merchant-form.blade.php` look like this

```
<form method="post" action="{{ $paytm_txn_url}}" name="f1">

    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($paramList as $name => $value) {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $value . '">';
        }
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="<?php echo $checkSum ?>">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.f1.submit();
    </script>
</form>
```

my route are as below

`Route::post('/paytm-callback','PaymentController@paytmCallback');`

`Route::resource('orders', 'UserResource\OrderResource');`

Callback URL function like this

`public function paytmCallback( Request $request ) {
        echo 'test';
    }`

After running this I am getting this error.

`TokenMismatchException`

[image: TokenMismatchException]

Comment: try to use `document.getElementByName('f1').item(0).submit();` and  `@csrf`, and clear cache

Comment: Check `configs/session.php#domain`. Maybe your session cookie is different from the local domain